# ASP.NET chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have heard about the new chart control. What format do these charts render on the page? Flash, Sikverlight, images, etc.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 3):

The output is rendered as an image, e.g. PNG. [See here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) for a description.

Answer (score 1):

The Chart control always renders as an image.

There are some additional rendering options, such as where the file is saved (memory, folder, etc.), but ultimately it is always rendered out in an `<img>` tag.